# Modify an XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have two files, file1 and file2.
I have to modify file1 in a particular node  and add in a list of children.
The list is in file2.
Can I do it, and how?

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
from xml.dom import minidom  
file1=modificare.xml
file2=sorgente.xml

xmldoc=minidom.parse(file1)

for Node in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Sampler"):
    # put in the file2 content
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ElementTree:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

# Configure one attribute with set()
root = Element('opml')
root.set('version', '1.0')

root.append(Comment('Generated by ElementTree_csv_to_xml.py for PyMOTW'))
```

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/03/pymotw-creating-xml-documents.html